# unix script - delimit output but character other than \n

Tags: unix, ls

What's a simple way (e.g. no perl) to turn the output of (e.g.) ls into ":"-delimited instead of "\n"-delimited?
I'm hoping for a sed or possibly awk short one-liner, I couldn't figure out how to get those to treat `\n` as a character that wasn't a line-delimiter though. 
I know Perl regexes provide this via an option, I think /m or /s or something. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls | tr "\n" :
ls | awk -vORS=: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at the most venerable tr ?

```
ls | tr "\n" "."
```

if I remember well.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try to use tr, I think it is one char only.

```
ls | tr '\n' '+'
```